# Zeppelin Oracle SQL query runs forewer

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to use Zeppelin (v 0.7.0 java 1.8 on Windows 10; same with [docker](https://github.com/dylanmei/docker-zeppelin)  v .0.7.1) JDBC interpreter to query Oracle Database.

So far I've found papers like [example](http://developers-club.com/posts/269769/). I  try to use jdbc interpreter with:

```
common.max_count=100
default.driver=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource 
default.password:$password
default.user=$my_user_name
default.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@$host:1521/$service_name>
zeppelin.jdbc.concurrent.max_connection=10
zeppelin.jdbc.concurrent.use=true
```

Connection looks to be established successfully*, but even simplest query (like `sql% select 1 from dual`) runs for ever.

Does anyone knows/have a clue on what is to be added?

what I see in terminal - repeating lines

> sKey: shared_process for InterpreterSetting Id: 2CMBZV4T1, Name: jdbc
>   DEBUG [2017-06-15 16:03:28,203] ({Thread-90} InterpreterSetting.java[getInterpreterProcessKey]:143) - getInterpreterProcessKey: shared_process for InterpreterSetting Id: 2CMBZV4T1, Name: jdbc
>   DEBUG [2017-06-15 16:03:28,204] ({Thread-90} InterpreterSetting.java[getInterpreterProcessKey]:143) - getInterpreterProcessKey: shared_process for InterpreterSetting Id: 2CMBZV4T1, Name: jdbc
>   DEBUG [2017-06-15 16:03:28,204] ({Thread-90} InterpreterFactory.java[getInterpreterSessionKey]:1244) - Interpreter session key: shared_session, for note: 2CMEC9SS4, user: anonymous, InterpreterSetting Name: jdbc
>   DEBUG [2017-06-15 16:03:28,205] ({Thread-90} InterpreterSetting.java[getInterpreterProcessKey]:143) - getInterpreterProcessKey: shared_process for InterpreterSetting Id: 2CMBZV4T1, Name: jdbc
>   DEBUG [2017-06-15 16:03:28,205] ({Thread-90} InterpreterSetting.java[getInterpreterProcessKey]:143) - getInterpreterProcessKey: shared_process for InterpreterSetting Id: 2CMBZV4T1, Name: jdbc

In the same time I don't have an issue using spark interpretor with scala over jdbc same driver.

- at least when I provide wrong password it prints meaningful response

Comment: Bogdan any update on that issue, i am facing the same issue. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure a query is running?

```
selec 1 from dual
```

is not valid SQL.

Check on Oracle side in gv$session for your query.  If it is running, it will be there.

Comment: thank you, description updated. Correct sql/bad sql-the same result

Comment: Check on Oracle side in gv$session for your query. If it is running, it will be there.