# Apache Zeppelin 0.7.3 - Oracle JDBC Issues & Long Running Query

Tags: oracle, apache, jdbc, apache-zeppelin

I am attempting to connect to an Oracle 12.1 database via Apache Zeppelin 0.7.3 and a simple query like: select sysdate from dual runs in excess of 10 minutes before completing.

The JDBC logs in $zeppelin_home/logs shows:

```
    ERROR [2017-12-08 14:08:58,068] ({pool-2-thread-2} JDBCInterpreter.java[open]:177) - zeppelin will be ignored. driver.zeppelin and zeppelin.url is mandatory.
```

I have connected without issue to a MySql database in this same environment so the issue appears to be specific to Oracle. I have checked in gv$session and see the session created shortly after (a couple seconds) the Zeppelin query is executed.  Activity on the database seems to show that an extended period of time is spent doing logic reads via nested loop on a large dictionary query that starts like this:

```
   SELECT  NULL AS table_cat,
   t.owner AS table_schem,
   t.table_name AS table_name,
   t.column_name AS column_name,
   DECODE (t.data_type, 'CHAR', 1, 'VARCHAR2', 12, 'NUMBER', 3,
   ...
```

Questions:

1. Does anyone know how to disable this potentially useless and problematic dictionary query?
2. Does anyone know any way around this issue, at all?
3. Has anyone heard of a target release date for Zeppelin 0.8, which will hopefully have a fix in place?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568223/zeppelin-oracle-sql-query-runs-forewer) old posting that described similar issues but without any helpful responses.

Answer (score 1):

1. In version 0.7.3 the query to metadata always runs before the paragraph query.
   This query in the master branch runs asynchronously.
2. This is no easy workaround.
   You can read the source code. Your query starts here:
   https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/branch-0.7/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/jdbc/SqlCompleter.java#L122
3. A lot of people wait 0.8.0. Now there are no any plans.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  Not what I was hoping for but helpful responses nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, it's fixed in the current master version. Build it from source and will work just fine. Note that at the time of writing, master build fails to compile because of the R interpreter, just omit to include the `-Dr` flag and you'll be good. Follow instruction on README file.

Comment: I am using the latest version 0.7.3 and installed via tarball instead of building from source.  Are you suggesting that building from source will somehow circumvent that issue?  Thanks.

Comment: Correct, you need to build from source because the last official release doesn't yet support this new feature.